# How to find parent and the parent of the parent for a given child without recursion?

Tags: c#, tree

I have a very large in memory List, I'm looking for the most efficient algorithm to take a list of Items, and finding all of parents when child is provided.

```
List<Data> elements = new List<Data>
{
    new Data {Id = 1, ParentId = null },
    new Data {Id = 2, ParentId = 1},
    new Data {Id = 3, ParentId = 2},
    new Data {Id = 4, ParentId = 3}
};

var parents =
    elements
        .Where(x => x.ParentId != null)
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Id, x => x.ParentId.Value);

IEnumerable<int> GetParents(int i) =>
    parents.ContainsKey(i)
        ? new[] { parents[i] }.Concat(GetParents(parents[i]))
        : Enumerable.Empty<int>();
var result = GetParents(3); //1,2
```

This works fine, but Its not efficient way.
How can the code be rewritten so that no recursive calls to Execute are made?

Comment: How do you envision traversing that data set then, if it is unknown?

Comment: Is it slow?  What is the problem with the current way?

Comment: I like to do the same, without using recursion?

Comment: @ElhamAzadfar I understand, but under what notion?   You almost would like the method to assume or guess to come to the right solution in a nondeterministic manner.

Comment: I want to find  most efficient algorithm.

Comment: So what problems did you have writing an iterative solution, rather than a recursive one?  As with any loop the ideas are pretty simple, you need a starting place, a way to determine if you're done, and a way to get the next item.  You already have all of those things, you just need to stick them into a loop statement (take your pick of which one you want to use).

Comment: Are you trying to do this to potentially traverse the Asp.Net controls on a page?

Answer (score 2):

An non recursive solution is pretty straightforward:

```
var currentId = i;

while (parents.TryGetValue(currentId, out var parentId))
{
    yield return parentId;
    currentId = parentId;
}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

As you know any recursive approach is not a good choice where you are dealing with a big amount of data. Because of recursive calls using heap stack and after a while, you will get `StackOverFlowException`. So just as you asked I provided a simple-designed non-recursive implementation for your question.

** In this sample, I'm getting deep into the hierarchy just for 7000 levels down because the recursive approach raises `StackOverFlowException` for more than that.

** The non-recursive approach including the first node which has **`null`** value as `ParendId`.

** The non-recursive **execution time** is much better than the recursive one.

```
    public class Data
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    }

    static List<Data> elements = new List<Data>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //To fill up the list with huge number if items
        elements.Add(new Data() { Id = 1, ParentId = null });
        Enumerable.Range(2, 1000000).ToList().ForEach(x => elements.Add(new Data { Id = x, ParentId = x - 1 }));

        //Making dictionary as you did it
        var parents =elements.ToDictionary(x => x.Id, x => x.ParentId);


        /*Non-Recursive Approach*/
        IEnumerable<int?> GetNonRecursiveParents(int i)
        {
            List<int?> parentsList = new List<int?>();
            if (parents.ContainsKey(i))
            {
                var parentNode = parents[i];
                do
                {
                    parentsList.Add(parentNode);
                    parentNode = parents[parentNode.Value];                        
                }
                while (parentNode != null);
            }
            return parentsList;
        };
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        var r = GetNonRecursiveParents(7000);
        stopwatch.Stop();
        var elapsed1 = stopwatch.Elapsed;// Execution time: 00:00:00.0023625



        //Making dictionary as you did it
        parents = elements.Where(x => x.ParentId != null).ToDictionary(x => x.Id, x => x.ParentId);


        /*Recursive Approach*/
        IEnumerable<int?> GetParents(int i) =>
            parents.ContainsKey(i)
                ? new[] { parents[i] }.Concat(GetParents(parents[i].Value))
                : Enumerable.Empty<int?>();
        stopwatch.Restart();
        var result = GetParents(7000); 
        stopwatch.Stop();
        var elapsed2= stopwatch.Elapsed;// Execution time: 00:00:00.0040636
    }
```